# Editing php.ini file to solve unwanted exception

Tags: php, pdo

I'm in the middle of transferring my site over to another server and ran across this error when trying to load the main index file:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /htdocs/www/demoportal/login.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /htdocs/www/demoportal/login.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=db2....', '???', '???') #1 /htdocs/www/demoportal/index.php(3): require('/htdocs/www/dem...') #2 {main} thrown in /htdocs/www/demoportal/login.php on line 8
```

The line that apparently is giving an error is the following:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $database, $user, $password);
```

The version of PHP on my system is PHP Version 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0.

[image]

I'm not sure what I need to look for in the php.ini file to modify or edit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to change your code to use SQLite, or ask your hosting provider to install the MySQL PDO Drivers for you.

Comment: PHP needs to be initialized with `--with-pdo-mysql[=DIR]`, apparently it is not :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the MySQL PDO drivers installed/loaded.

Comment: extension=pdo_mysql.so is not commented out - what do I need to do?

Comment: And what if the pdo_mysql.so isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

> what I need to look for in the php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so (or .dll)
```